How does health regeneration work?
A tutorial prompt mentioned that I can regain health when my hunger is not depleted. In my experience, the health regeneration has been inconsistent. I'll only sometimes regain HP outside of battle, even when my hunger meter is not empty.
How does health regeneration work in Sakuna: Of Rice and Ruin?

According to Fel on a Steam discussions page,

When you eat food with "natural healing" during a meal it provides you HP regen out of combat (you need to wait a few seconds with no enemies attacking you before it kicks in) but only while your food meter is still active (not empty).

According to an iMore page,

Finally, Sakuna's health can regenerate while in a level but not in combat, but only if she is currently still "full" from a meal, so make sure you eat often.


Ah, I hadn't unlocked the ability to choose my meals yet, so I hadn't seen anything with natural healing
